# Nginx screen pops up on website homepage but rest of site works fine

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am working with a localhost site and been checking my nginx configuration files over and over again because the default homepage screen shows the 'WELCOME TO NGINX!" title. After awhile I figured out by typing /user I was able to by-pass the homescreen and actually able to login to the site. Everything works EXCEPT the homepage screen, which gets directed to the NGINX home screen page. I'm a bit a a loss as to why this is. Here is my nginx conf file:

```
server {
server_name zeragames.localhost;
root /var/www/html/zeragames/web; ## <-- Your only path reference.

location = /favicon.ico {
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

# Very rarely should these ever be accessed outside of your lan
location ~* \.(txt|log)$ {
    allow 192.168.0.0/16;
    deny all;
}

location ~ \..*/.*\.php$ {
    return 403;
}

location ~ ^/sites/.*/private/ {
    return 403;
}

# Block access to scripts in site files directory
location ~ ^/sites/[^/]+/files/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
}

# Allow "Well-Known URIs" as per RFC 5785
location ~* ^/.well-known/ {
    allow all;
}

# Block access to "hidden" files and directories whose names begin with a
# period. This includes directories used by version control systems such
# as Subversion or Git to store control files.
location ~ (^|/)\. {
    return 403;
}

location / {
    # try_files $uri @rewrite; # For Drupal <= 6
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string; # For Drupal >= 7
}

location @rewrite {
    #rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1; # For Drupal <= 6
    rewrite ^ /index.php; # For Drupal >= 7
}

# Don't allow direct access to PHP files in the vendor directory.
location ~ /vendor/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}

# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
location ~* \.(engine|inc|install|make|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|twig|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|yml)(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)?$|/(\.(?!well-known).*)|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|composer\.(json|lock)|web\.config$|/#.*#$|\.php(~|\.sw[op]|\.bak|\.orig|\.save)$ {
    deny all;
    return 404;
}

# In Drupal 8, we must also match new paths where the '.php' appears in
# the middle, such as update.php/selection. The rule we use is strict,
# and only allows this pattern with the update.php front controller.
# This allows legacy path aliases in the form of
# blog/index.php/legacy-path to continue to route to Drupal nodes. If
# you do not have any paths like that, then you might prefer to use a
# laxer rule, such as:
#   location ~ \.php(/|$) {
# The laxer rule will continue to work if Drupal uses this new URL
# pattern with front controllers other than update.php in a future
# release.
location ~ '\.php$|^/update.php' {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(|/.*)$;
    # Ensure the php file exists. Mitigates CVE-2019-11043
    try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404;
    # Security note: If you're running a version of PHP older than the
    # latest 5.3, you should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini.
    # See http://serverfault.com/q/627903/94922 for details.
    include fastcgi_params;
    # Block httpoxy attacks. See https://httpoxy.org/.
    fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    # PHP 5 socket location.
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    # PHP 7 socket location.
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}

location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}

# Fighting with Styles? This little gem is amazing.
# location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/imagecache/ { # For Drupal <= 6
location ~ ^/sites/.*/files/styles/ { # For Drupal >= 7
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

# Handle private files through Drupal. Private file's path can come
# with a language prefix.
location ~ ^(/[a-z\-]+)?/system/files/ { # For Drupal >= 7
    try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
}

# Enforce clean URLs
# Removes index.php from urls like www.example.com/index.php/my-page --> www.example.com/my-page
# Could be done with 301 for permanent or other redirect codes.
if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*/)index\.php/(.*)") {
    return 307 $1$2;
}
```

}

host file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   zeragames.localhost


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

My main question: How do I get the homepage screen to work showing Welcome to Drupal 8! instead of pointing to the NGINX homescreen? As stated above, every other page works and is accessible. Just the homepage itself isn't!

Comment: Sounds like you have Drupal installed?  Where is it installed?  What is in `/var/www/html/zeragames/web`?

Comment: Yes I have drupal installed. Basically the path file you listed is my root directory for my drupal installation. Any part of the website is accessible and usable. Only when I go directly to my home page, which is zeragames.localhost, does it instead point to nginx homepage. I don't understand why its pointing there and not to my Drupal Pathway when the rest of the site works normal!

Comment: Is there an `index.html` or `index.something.html` type file in that dir?